# Sounds continues on pause and stop with autoplay video.js in Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, html5-video, autoplay

I am trying to use video.js in a Fancybox pop up with autoplay. The video autoplays as expected, but when I pause or close the window the sound continues. I tried to use "onClose" and "afterClose" to remove the player, but it didn't help.

Here is a link to my page: http://dev.sterlingklor.com/projects/ilovetreasury/events/1tc-2013#video21

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var videobox = $('#video').first();
    $(".various").fancybox({
        fitToView: true,
        autoSize: true,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        href: this.href,
        content: '<video autoplay preload="none" width="640" height="360" controls="controls"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">your browser does not support the HTML 5 video tag</video>',
        onClosed: function () {
            $('video').remove();
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $('video').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your issue is basically created while playing "inline" videos. If you are not married to video.js, you might be interested in playing your (mp4) videos dynamically with mediaelement.js in fancybox. Check my tutorial at http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [created a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XDZQ6/3/) attempting to do what you are trying.

I first created a standalone video element and container and hid them.  This should eliminate the 2+ audio tracks by always being the same video element and not creating a new one on each click.

Then I set up fancy box to reset the video to 0 and tell it to play on showing (`afterShow`). And told it to pause before closing (`beforeClose`).

**notice**

the video does use the `autoplay` attribute and includes `preload="meta"` to ensure the video length is known when we try to set the `currentTime`.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Hi. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I notice now that I hear two audio tracks at the same time slightly off synch. I checked through the source and the video is only being called once.

Comment: which browser are you in?  Chrome on mac didn't auto play and closed successfully (stopped) on your site.

Comment: Firefox 30 for Windows. Chrome on Windows doesn't autoplay for me either.

Comment: In IE10 the video auto plays and then pauses and stops correctly. But when I click on the video to play a second time I get the double audio track.

Comment: The fiddle works beautifully, exactly like I want it do.  BUT I can't get it to work on my page. I still get the double audio track. I even copied the code bit by bit.